# Strange behaviour on /deny DE,W with icacls

Tags: permissions, icacls, microsoft

I have the following scenario where I (`admin`) applied the `(DE,W)` deny permissions to the following folder `test_folder` for `test_user` who already has inherited modify permissions from parent folder:

```
B:\>icacls test_folder
test_folder     test_user:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
                admin:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)

B:\>icacls test_folder /deny test_user:(DE,W)

B:\>icacls test_folder
test_folder     test_user:(DENY)(W,D)
                test_user:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
                admin:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
```

The end result I would expected is `test_user` being able to have read/execute access to  `test_folder` without being able to delete/rename the folder and add folders/files to it.

However, the result was `test_folder` not being visible to `test_user` at all. The `test_folder` is still visible to me (`admin`).

While I deny only `DE` however:

```
B:\>icacls test_folder
test_folder     test_user:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
                admin:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)

B:\>icacls test_folder /deny test_user:(DE)

B:\>icacls test_folder
test_folder     test_user:(DENY)(D)
                test_user:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
                admin:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
```

`test_user` was able to see `test_folder`. So somehow `W` is causing an issue.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `(W)` and `(M)` are macros; they expand to multiple actual access flags.

In particular, `(W)` like [FILE_GENERIC_WRITE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights) grants these rights:

- "Synchronize" `(S)`
- "Write data" `(WD)`
- "Append data" `(AD)`
- "Write EAs" `(WEA)`
- "Write attributes" `(WA)`

The "Synchronize" right is rather obscure (and not even shown in the GUI), but it's one that is necessary for practically any kind of useful access to the file – it's needed for both reading *and* writing, and is therefore included in **both "(R)" and "(W)"** sets.

So when you deny (W) access, you also end up denying the "Synchronize" right, which is required for many programs to operate on the file at all.

Microsoft's [file access documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights) also notes this:

> Note that you cannot use an access-denied ACE to deny only GENERIC_READ or only GENERIC_WRITE access to a file. This is because for file objects, the generic mappings for both GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE include the SYNCHRONIZE access right. If an ACE denies GENERIC_WRITE access to a trustee, and the trustee requests GENERIC_READ access, the request will fail because the request implicitly includes SYNCHRONIZE access which is implicitly denied by the ACE, and vice versa. Instead of using access-denied ACEs, use access-allowed ACEs to explicitly allow the permitted access rights.

If you must use a "deny" ACE, you'll need to individually deny the four other rights that (W) includes, i.e. `(WD,AD,WEA,WA)`, but note that such an ACE tends to confuse ACL editing tools a little. (Many will still collapse it to a generic "Write" and you won't be able to tell the difference.)

The older `cacls` tool is particularly useful here, as it doesn't know many new macros/aliases and as a result shows you all the individual access rights. Alternatively, PowerShell's `Get-Acl` is normally too fine-grained to be useful, but in this case it's fine-grained just enough to be useful:

```
PS C:\> icacls test /grant "user:(OI)(CI)(R,X)"
PS C:\> icacls test /deny "user:(OI)(CI)(W)"

PS C:\> Get-Acl test | fl
Access : FOO\user Deny  Write, Synchronize
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         FOO\user Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize

PS C:\> cacls test  
C:\test FOO\user (OI)(CI)(DENY)(special access:)
                                  SYNCHRONIZE
                                  FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                  FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                  FILE_WRITE_EA
                                  FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
        FOO\user:(OI)(CI)(DENY)(special access:)
                                  DELETE
                                  SYNCHRONIZE
        BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F
        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F
```

Comment: gotcha. So it seems denying `(R)` or `(W)` is a bad idea as it messes with the `(S)` which is crucial. Will try to restructure, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Many (most?) applications don't use "synchronize", but *because it's included in the GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE sets* they request it anyway when they request generic read or write.